# Name 'Model' is not declared in a strongly typed view - ASPNET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

As of recent, a few of my strongly typed views randomly (w/ zero code changes) decided that 'Model' was not a valid item ... again - ZERO code changes.  I simply opened my view and now it's broken ... so logically I deleted the view and created a new one - still broken.  Has anyone else come across this issue using MVC?  A simple example is below

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of IEnumerable (Of Project.Library.Entity.User))" %>

    <table id="tblUser" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
        <% For Each item In Model%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=Html.Encode(item.Username)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% Next%>
      </table>
```

The actual error shows up in the view - under the word "Model" is a red line and when I hover over this (in any of my partial views - strongly typed) it says "Name 'Model' is not declared"

Comment: Aren't you possibly running the project against one of the previous betas?

Comment: Just to clarify - this is MVC 1.0 (never installed any other version on my machine)

Comment: Please, post the error message, it might be helpful.

Comment: Funny thing is .. I create a new project - add refs to my class library and now it's fine ... maybe my sln got modified or something crazy?  When I go back to the broken solution now, it acts like the project is not MVC related ...

Comment: What does it say the type of 'Me' is when it does this?

Answer (score 2):

'Model' is a property of the ViewUserControl class, so when it's marked as not declared this may mean the following:

1. There is no such property in ViewUserControl. This can be when an old version of System.Web.Mvc is used. To check this just try to delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc, and add it again and run the application. If the error in editor still exists, see case 2.
2. Some of the plugins think that there is no such method. Or aliens hacked your VS. You can try to reload the VS or to repair it and after repair ASP.NET MVC.

Hope this will help.